# Apple Push Notification not working with ad-hoc provisioning profile

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

There are a lot of related/similar questions here but none exactly capture my situation. I switched from a dev provisioning profile using the sandbox server:

```
$apns = stream_socket_client(
                             'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195',
                             $error,
                             $errorString,
                             2,
                             STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);
```

(WHICH WORKS)

to a production provisioning profile using the production APNS server:

```
$apns = stream_socket_client(
                             'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195',
                             $error,
                             $errorString,
                             2,
                             STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);
```

(DOESN'T WORK)

My device token changed, which reflects that my app is switched over to production. However, no messages are received on my device.

I'm able to telnet into the production server. I receive no errors in $errorString and everything seems fine...well, except for the no notifications part.

I've tried restarting my device, which does not work. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked settings in device, is your apps push notifications are allowed on device. If it is allowed then check your .p12 file, it should be only private key of your APNS production certificate.

Comment: @AshishP. Notifications are allowed. The sandbox token worked fine. It's production that is not working. the .p12 file is what allows connection to the apple server, if I'm not mistaken, and that's working fine.